# Group by and then ungroup causes loss of all events on beam TestPipeline

Tags: apache-beam

We found this line(mainly the reshuffle to be INTERMITTENTLY dropping events(causing flaky tests) on apache beam org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline ->

```
    PCollection<OrderlyBeamDto<RosterRecord>> records = PCollectionList.of(csv.get(TupleTags.OUTPUT_RECORD)).and(excel.get(TupleTags.OUTPUT_RECORD))
        .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
        .apply("Reshuffle Records", Reshuffle.viaRandomKey());
```

soooo, I modified it to this and now we lose ALL events.  In fact, the UngroupFn() is never called

```
    PCollection<OrderlyBeamDto<RosterRecord>> records = PCollectionList.of(csv.get(TupleTags.OUTPUT_RECORD)).and(excel.get(TupleTags.OUTPUT_RECORD))
        .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new CreateKeyFn()))
        .apply(GroupByKey.<String, OrderlyBeamDto<RosterRecord>>create())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new UngroupFn()));
```

The code for Ungroup is simply this

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(final ProcessContext c) {
    log.info("running ungroup");
    KV<String, Iterable<OrderlyBeamDto<RosterRecord>>> keyValue = c.element();

    Iterable<OrderlyBeamDto<RosterRecord>> list = keyValue.getValue();
    for(OrderlyBeamDto<RosterRecord> record : list) {
        log.info("ungroup="+record.getValue().getRowNumber());
        c.output(record);
    }
}
```

**We never see the 'running ungroup' log :(**

Comment: sorry about the delay on this. What's your source for this?

Comment: We moved to cloud run and off of dataflow for much easier traceability and debugging.  we lose joins and have to deal with that but the datasets are also not huge.

Comment: makes sense. Glad you could work it out : )